# Typescript Type Guards and fat arrow function

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Shouldn't this compile correctly? I get an error `"Property 'hello' does not exist on type 'object'.`" in the highlighted line.

I can access `g.hello` outside the fat arrow function without problems.

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
    }
    hello() : string {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

let g : object;

if (g instanceof Test) {
    () => {
        g.hello();    ////// ERROR HERE /////
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The narrowing that a type-guard does on a variable (or anything else) will not cross fucntion boundaries. This is a design limitation.

A way to work around this issue is to assign `g` to a new variable, which will have it's type inferred based on the narrowing. Accessing the new variable in the arrow function will work as expected:

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
    }
    hello() : string {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

let g : object;

if (g instanceof Test) {
    const gTest = g;
    () => {
        gTest.hello();
    };
}
```

Another way to work around this issue if `g` does not change, is to declare `g` with `const`. This will let the compiler preserve the narrowing:

```
let g : object;

if (g instanceof Test) {
    const gTest = g;
    () => {
        gTest.hello();
    };
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEAqBTKAXWBvYtuxAewDtUAnAVxBT2IAoBKDLHAX0ewAtEww87YAuWCQCWBAOYMck2MUQpSxArABEACU7clAblawWLYABNE4CDNyFUscQLwAjAFbGU24EIBmsauJGoIBEIh4Hkio9JiSvAC8AHwSUtiiAHQcXDy02pJM2kxAA)

Comment: Ah the 'ol that = this +1

Comment: @ChrisW. old solution with new use cases ;)

Comment: I think this answer is either partially incorrect or outdated. In TypeScript 3+, type guards can cross function boundaries for `const`-declared variables. Changing line 9 in the original question to `const g: object = new Test();` allows it to compile without errors. (It makes sense that `let` narrowing would not cross function boundaries because the variable could be reassigned back to an `object` before the function is called.)

Comment: @Miles Nope, the issue is still there, specifically it has to do with the arrow function `() =>`  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEAqBTKAXWBvYtuxAewDtUAnAVxBT2IAoBKDLHAX0ewAtEww87YAuWCQCWBAOYMck2MUQpSxArABEACU7clAblawWLYABNE4CDNhhZscQLwAjAFbGU24EIBmsauJGoIBEIh4Hkio9JiSvAC8AHwSUtiiAHQcXDy02pJM2kxAA

Comment: You're using `let`, I said `const`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEAqBTKAXWBvYtuxAewDtUAnAVxBT2IAoBKDLHAX0ewAtEww87YAuWCQCWBAOYMck2MUQpSxArABEACU7clAblawWLYABNE4CDNyFUscQLwAjAFbGU24EIBmsauJGoIBEIh4Hkio9JiSvAC8AHwSUtiiAHQcXDy02pJM2kxAA That looks like narrowing crossing function boundaries to me.

Comment: @Miles You are right, this seems to have changed, or I missed it at the time. I will add this workaroudn as well

Answer (score 0):

### let + arrow function

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
    }
    hello() : string {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

declare let g : object;

if (g instanceof Test) {
    () => {
        g.hello(); // error
    };
}
```

`g` is a `Test` when the function is defined, but `g` may not be `Test` when the function runs.

### const + arrow function

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
    }
    hello() : string {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

declare const g : object;

if (g instanceof Test) {
    () => {
        g.hello(); // ok
    };
}
```

`g` is immutable, `g` is always a `Test` after the function is defined.

### const + regular function

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
    }
    hello() : string {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

declare const g : object;

if (g instanceof Test) {
    function f() {
        g.hello(); // error
    };
}
```

Within underlying implementation, regular function `f` is defined by ES5 `var`, instead of ES6 `let`. [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) hoists declaration of `f`, when `g` may not be a `Test`.